# ContentProvider How call method

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have a contentprovider, which i am using. Within the contentProvider, I call a method in oncreate(), which sets a lot of default values for the content provider. 
I am using the content provider by another table for each entry. So, when I create a new entry in the other table, I would like to override the settings of the content provider. How can I call the method within the contentProvider, which sets default values? Since the onCreate is not called again, I do not get the default settings.

I also thought about the following approach, but this seems to be difficult as well.

Is it possible to generically copy all columns of a row and change only one column? I want to specify the column, which should be replaced, not all of the other ones...

As I have mentioned, I want to insert default values, so I am not planning to copy too much rows, which would be bad database design.

Example Table MyFavorites blob bla, String link, ....., String nameToReplace, ...

Lets say I have 20 columns. I want to copy anything, and I just want to change the nametoReplace.

Best Regards,

Patrick